# AWS Amplify -- AppSync Offline

Tags: apollo, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

Does Amplify support the Offline capabilities outlined here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/building-a-client-app-react.html#offline-settings

Should I set it up like this?
https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/media/api_guide#configuration-for-graphql-server

Or for offline capabilities, do I have to use something like Apollo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a difference between AWS Amplify and AWS App Sync.

[AWS Amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/introducing-aws-amplify-a-declarative-javascript-library-for-cloud-development-with-mobile-or-web-applications/) is a [library](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js) for web and mobile developement in JavaScript providing better access to AWS services like Auth, Analytics, Storage, APIs, Caching.

AWS AppSync is a combination of service that works as a GraphQL server and SDK (for [web](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js), iOS and Android). This SDK extends Apollo Client to provide capabilities like Offline and Realtime synchronization out of the box.

So, to answer your question: AWS AppSync does provide offline via its SDK out of the box and you shouldn’t need to do anything specifically to set up that.